# groupby in Pandas -Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am getting an error message when I try to perform an operation in a groupby object which I do not understand.

For a reproducible example consider the following:

```
import pandas as pd

species_plots_types



 record_id  plot_id plot_type   species_id
    0       1   2   Control NL
    2194    2   3   Long-term Krat Exclosure    NL
    1       3   2   Control DM
    4022    4   7   Rodent Exclosure    DM
    2195    5   3   Long-term Krat Exclosure    DM
    4838    6   1   Spectab exclosure   PF
    2       7   2   Control PE
    4839    8   1   Spectab exclosure   DM
    4840    9   1   Spectab exclosure   DM
    6833    10  6   Short-term Krat Exclosure   PF
    8415    11  5   Rodent Exclosure    DS
    4023    12  7   Rodent Exclosure    DM
    2196    13  3   Long-term Krat Exclosure    DM
    9609    14  8   Control DM
    6834    15  6   Short-term Krat Exclosure   DM

species_plots_types.groupby["plot_type"].size().to_frame()

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

species_plots_types.groupby["plot_type"].count()

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Use parentheses:

```
species_plots_types.groupby("plot_type").count()
```

Instead of square brackets

```
species_plots_types.groupby["plot_type"].count()
```

Refer the given [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

You need `()`:

```
species_plots_types.groupby("plot_type").size().to_frame()
```

Or:

```
species_plots_types.groupby("plot_type").count()
```

Explanation:

`groupby["plot_type"]` means you call `__getitem__` on `groupby`, but since this method isn't defined, you get a `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`. Check python documentation for [getitem](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) for more details.